# ASP.net Call function in Default.aspx.cs from the Site.Master.cs class

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications

So on my Default.aspx page I have several listboxes which I am populating on page_load.

However, if the user changes these listboxes and wants to restore the original settings, I want a button at the top, which is defined in the Site.Master, to call this same function gain to restore the original values.

How can I obtain a reference to an instance of the _Default object from the Site.Master file? Is there a way to globally access the instance of _Default that is called when the page is first loaded? Or do I need to store that manually somewhere?

For example:

Default.aspx.cs:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setConfigurationData();
        }

        public void setConfigurationData()
        {
            //Do stuff to elements on Default.aspx
```

Site.Master.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void RefreshMenu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
        {
            //Need to call this function from an instance of _Default, but I don't know
            //how to retrive this or save it from when it is first created

            //_Default.setConfigurationData();
```

Comment: If your master page needs implementation details of any specific page, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @JoelEtherton, although I agree, I think his intentions are different. He wants to declare a single button on a master that will work differently on many pages, not hold logic for a specific page. That doesn't necessarily mean it's right, though.

Comment: @DaveZych: My comment is not meant as a disparagement, just as a minor voice of reason. Once this bridge appears, there is almost always a simpler method of achieving the desired effect. I would recommend OP search for that method.

Comment: @JoelEtherton - DaveZych is correct. I have a "clear" button which I would like to call for 5 different configuration page "tabs". This button is defined in the Site.Master header and is present on each page, along with the tab controls. Is this a bad approach?

Comment: @jamis0n: In my opinion yes. Common functionality of this sort should belong to a page base class rather than the master page. The master page is there to define layout and overall common functionality in a general sense. I think it would be wiser to have a method in your page base class which performs this function. If you need to communicate between multiple controls it might be wiser (though not necessarily simpler) to wire it up using events.

Comment: @jamis0n: As a disclaimer, this is just my opinion from a purist standpoint (the cheap seats I guess). The best approach is generally the one that is the easiest to implement and maintain while getting it done on time.

Comment: @JoelEtherton Thanks for your honest opinions! And I would agree with them both. Part of this is me learning how it all works in C# and ASP.net, and as such, I'm going to try both ways so I can understand it best. Appreciate your best practice advice though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this class scoped variable to your Master page

```
private System.Web.UI.Page currentContentPage = new System.Web.UI.Page();
```

Then add this method to your Master page

```
public void childIdentity(System.Web.UI.Page childPage)
{
    currentContentPage = childPage;
}
```

Now in the Page_Load of your Default page add

```
SiteMaster masterPage = Page.Master as SiteMaster;
masterPage.childIdentity(this);
```

Now your master page should be able to access the objects on the Default page through the reference in its currentContentPage variable.

Comment: I like this approach, effectively registering with the Site Master the current page. However, I cannot get it to work with this code: `_Default myDefault = (_Default) currentContentPage;` then `myDefault.setConfigurationData();`

Comment: Nevermind- It was an issue with my click event... Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Create a base class for your page to inherit from, with a virtual method named `setConfigurationData`. Then in your Master page, cast the `Page` object to your base class and call your method.

```
public class MyBasePage : Page
{
    public virtual void setConfigurationData()
    {
        //Default code if you want it
    }
}
```

In your page:

```
public partial class MyPage : MyBasePage
{
    public override void setConfigurationData()
    {
        //You code to do whatever
    }
}
```

Master page:

```
protected void RefreshMenu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    MyBasePage basePage = (MyBasePage)Page;
    basePage.setConfigurationData();
}
```